# Inner Join and Coalesce issue

Tags: sql-server

I am running this query and getting error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near '.'.
>
> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'and'.

My target table contains NULLs and source contains NULLs and data.

I need to fill the target with the addresses from the source table.

```
DECLARE @FullStatement nvarchar(4000)
SET @FullStatement= ' Using ' + @TargetTable+ ' AS itarget'+
                            ' USING '+@CurrentTable+' AS isource

SELECT 
    isource.[Address], itarget.[Address]
FROM 
    isource 
INNER JOIN 
    itarget ON target.VersionEndDate IS NULL 
            AND target.ResearchPropertyId = source.ResearchPropertyId
     (coalesce(isource.[Address], '') = coalesce(itarget.[Addres], '')) and 
     (coalesce(itarget.[Address], '') = coalesce(isource.[Address], ''))'

IF @debug = 1 
   PRINT @FullStatement

EXECUTE sp_executesql @FullStatement
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change each '' to '''' in this block:

```
 (coalesce(isource.[Address], '') = coalesce(itarget.[Addres], '')) and 
     (coalesce(itarget.[Address], '') = coalesce(isource.[Address], ''))
```

Comment: Thanks Anoton. I get this error now...                                                      Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: when you print the message, you have to be able to run that script. If it is not failing, then EXECUTE should not fail as well.  Your script has some typos, like Addres, source instead of isource, target instead of itarget, etc. Fix all of them, print the "@FullStatement" and try to copy-paste and execute it without EXECUTE. If it's still failing, edit your post and add that value of "@FullStatement"

Comment: I removed the typos and no error anymore. However the Target column did not get updated. I think I need to use MERGE?

Comment: Yes, of course. I thought you removed it just for this question to focus on your issues with Coalesce. See this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx - it has an example (on the bottom of page) and full description how to use MERGE. There are a lot of "merge" examples online.

Answer (score 0):

A `AND` and `single quotes` are missing.

```
DECLARE @FullStatement nvarchar(4000)
SET @FullStatement= ' Using ' + @TargetTable+ ' AS itarget'+
                            ' USING '+@CurrentTable+' AS isource

SELECT 
    isource.[Address], itarget.[Address]
FROM 
    isource 
INNER JOIN 
    itarget ON target.VersionEndDate IS NULL 
            AND target.ResearchPropertyId = source.ResearchPropertyId AND -- Here Need a AND
     (coalesce(isource.[Address], '''') = coalesce(itarget.[Addres], '''')) and 
     (coalesce(itarget.[Address], '''') = coalesce(isource.[Address], ''''))'

IF @debug = 1 
   PRINT @FullStatement

EXECUTE sp_executesql @FullStatement
```